# How to export BOM from inventor to the forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

So we are working with forge we are opening our inventor model. We can see the iLogic and parameters are working fine model is working fine. Only problem is that we can not see the BOM in the forge. I did edit and made BOM in the inventor but whenever we extract the model to the forge platform we cannot see the BOM. Is there anything I should do to enable it in Inventor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is how the main DA4I sample extracts the BOM: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/AppBundles/ExportBOMPlugin/ExportBOMAutomation.cs
Are you using the same code? Do you get some errors?